# Build curl source code with Visual Studio Developer command line (NMAKE)

Tags: c, visual-studio, curl, libcurl, nmake

I want to use libcurl in my C program. So I have curl-7.87.0 but some errors happen in x64 build.

in x86 build does not have any errors but its have libcurl.lib not libcurl.a in libs.

To build in Visual Studio 2022 Developer command prompt:

```
 cd curl-7.87.0\winbuild

 nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=10 debug=no machine=x64
```

I guss "developer command prompt" uses x86 nmake. Like in image:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\ **HostX86\x86** \nmake.exe"

What can I do to solve it?
Thanks for any help.

I Copied all files of HostX64\x64 to HostX86\x86 and  build again but again those errors.

Comment: I just want to compile curl source code as 64bit, You mean this is nmake problem or curl source code?

Comment: Main thing, don't go moving around the VS files from HostX86 and HostX64, they are in the correct location, if you've messed these up, then your going to make fixing your issue 100% harder.

Comment: In my start menu I have both a x64 Native Tools Command Prompt, and an x86 Native Tools Command Prompt, this sets all of the required settings to correctly build, by calling vcvarsall.bat

Comment: From your current x86 command prompt you should be able to type `VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat` to switch to the x64 settings.